# Validate Jar file

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement where i need to upload only jar file.
If i upload any other image or text file..it should show up an error message.

This is the code that i have tried in javascript.Suggest me if there is any other way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function vali_type()
{ 
    alert('inside');
    var id_value = document.getElementById('up').value;
    if(id_value != '')
    { 
          var valid_extensions = /(.jar)$/i;   
          if(valid_extensions.test(id_value))
          { 
               alert('OK');
          }
          else
          {
               alert('Invalid File')
          }
    } 
}       
</script>
```

Comment: What has this to do with Java (in the first place). Also where is the question?

Comment: this is the code that i have written in jsp file

Comment: @saho but the snippet has nothing to do with Java. It could be also embedded in a PHP...

Comment: You can do this using the `FileAPI`, but it will work only for modern browsers (IE9 and below is not supported)

Comment: @Uwe plonus I knew nothing about php....my project is based on spring mvc and hibernate...and in jsp file i am doing this validation part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) to validate the file extension.

```
  var url = "http://www.somesite.com/dir1/dir2/filename.jar";
  var checkExt = /\.(jar)$/i.test(url);
  if (checkExt) {
      alert("Yup its a jar file");
  } else {
      alert("Nope");
  }
```

**EDIT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function vali_type(){ 
    alert('inside');
    var id_value = document.getElementById('up').value;
    if(id_value != '') { 
          var checkExt = /\.(jar)$/i.test(id_value );   
          if(checkExt ){ 
               alert('OK');
          }
          else{
               alert('Invalid File')
          }
    } 
}       
</script>
```

Comment: where did you get that url from??

Comment: @sahu Its a default example.  You should be using it like `var url= document.getElementById('up').value;`

Comment: @sahu I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use:

```
<input type="file" accept=".jar" />
```

You can then use that to add support in older browsers.

Comment: it was showing only jar files when i chose to upload..it was good. But i should have an option to upload even text or jpg files and then show up an error msg

Comment: @sahu I think its a bad idea to upload the files and then to check it whether jar or not.  Is there any specific reason for it?

Comment: Regarding to the above code : When i chose to upload a jar file i have an option to change the file type to all files...and it is accepting the text or jpg file also...so this is not what i want.

Comment: You would of course want to verify this on the server, and probably with JS as well, but this is the first step in doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this with the name only

```
function vali_type()
{ 
var id_value = "validate.jar"; //Let I assume this
  if(id_value != '')
  { 
      if(id_value.lastIndexOf(".jar") != -1)
      { 
           alert('OK');
      }
      else
      {
           alert('Invalid File')
      }
  } 
}
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/4crpv/)

Comment: @sahu what is the filename you get? What the error comes in console?